# can I convert a label that shows the time into a background color?

Tags: vb.net, colors, forms

I have a label that displays the time and I would like to convert that label.text into a color for the background that changes every time the time changes. Is this possible? My code is below.
Example:
If the time displayed is 11:23:04 I would like the background color to be changed to #112304.
If the time displayed is 11:24:00 I would like the background color to be changed to #112400.
etc. etc.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick

    Label1.Text = TimeOfDay

    Label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyy")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a new color by using the [FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557(v=vs.110).aspx). The TimeOfDay property is a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains a Hour, Minute and Second property.

```
Color.FromArgb(DateTime.TimeOfDay.Hour, DateTime.TimeOfDay.Minute, DateTime.TimeOfDay.Second)
```

This will use decimal, so 11:12:13 will be #0B0C0D if you want to use decimal format you'll need to convert it first.

Answer (score 0):

First Remove the ":" from the time and then convert it into a hex color

```
Dim remove = Label1.Text.Replace(":", "")
    Me.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & remove)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine Dmandy's ColorTranslator.FromHtml() approach and format the time as you've already demonstrated with ToString():

```
Me.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(DateTime.Now.ToString("#HHmmss"))
```