# How do I make it so that my hex color code does not have "PM" or "AM" at the end?

Tags: vb.net, colors, label

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = TimeOfDay
        Label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyy")
        Dim remove = Label1.Text.Replace(":", "")
        Me.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & remove)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I come up with an error that "12708PM" is not a valid hex code. How can I make it so that the "PM" or "AM" on my label does not come into the hex code? Also, is there any way I can make it so that it makes "1" or "2" come out to be "01" or "02"? I am a beginner, so I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Label1.text is what I need to worry about for my question. Label2.text simply shows the current date.

Comment: And how and when do you set that variable TimeOfDay?

Comment: Quick and dirty fix: 

    Dim remove = Label1.Text.Replace(":", "").Replace("PM", "").Replace("AM", "")

Comment: How do you set the timeofday variable?

Comment: several good answers on the original version: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27709835/1070452

Comment: @competent_tech that won't work because then the hex color will only have 4 digits and needs 6

Comment: @Dmandy how do you make it have 6?

Comment: Either add in random digits or numbers at the end or use @the_lotus' answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to get the value from the label, you already got it in a date format. Just convert the date into the preferred string format.

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"))
```

Comment: The "#" can be in the ToString() call itself, just like posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27710538/2330053) earlier.